# Running docker compose up outputs logs even when logging driver is set to none

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run tests for my app. My docker-compose.yml file has three services, one for mongodb, one for my app, and a third for my tests. I have logging: driver: "none" set for the app and mongodb because I only want to see the test logs.

This previously worked as expected. Since the last time I worked on this project, I've upgraded docker desktop on my mac to Version 3.5.2 (3.5.2.18). Now, all container logs flood my terminal when running. I'm not sure what has changed.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    logging:
      driver: "none"

  rsscloud:
    build: .
    command: node --use_strict app.js
    environment:
      DOMAIN: rsscloud
      PORT: 5337
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongodb:27017/rsscloud
      NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0
    expose:
      - 5337
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    logging:
      driver: "none"

  rsscloud-tests:
    build: .
    command: dockerize -wait tcp://mongodb:27017 -wait http://rsscloud:5337 -timeout 10s bash -c "npm test"
    environment:
      APP_URL: http://rsscloud:5337
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongodb:27017/rsscloud
      MOCK_SERVER_DOMAIN: rsscloud-tests
      MOCK_SERVER_PORT: 8002
      SECURE_MOCK_SERVER_PORT: 8003
    volumes:
      - ./xunit:/app/xunit
    expose:
      - 8002
      - 8003
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rsscloud
```

I run `docker compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit`

Here is a sample of the output:

```
Attaching to mongodb_1, rsscloud-tests_1, rsscloud_1
rsscloud-tests_1  | 2021/07/27 15:43:58 Waiting for: tcp://mongodb:27017
rsscloud-tests_1  | 2021/07/27 15:43:58 Waiting for: http://rsscloud:5337
rsscloud-tests_1  | 2021/07/27 15:43:58 Connected to tcp://mongodb:27017
mongodb_1         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-27T15:43:58.964+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.4:39890","uuid":"d9874a7d-e9c3-4e88-b163-c9b9deb582d1","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
rsscloud-tests_1  | 2021/07/27 15:43:58 Received 200 from http://rsscloud:5337
rsscloud_1        | [15:43:58.993] GET / 200 577 - ::ffff:172.18.0.4 - 20.885 ms
rsscloud-tests_1  | 
rsscloud-tests_1  | > rsscloud-server@2.0.0 test /app
rsscloud-tests_1  | > mocha -R mocha-multi --reporter-options spec=-,xunit=xunit/test-results.xml --timeout 10000
rsscloud-tests_1  | 
rsscloud-tests_1  | 
rsscloud-tests_1  | 
rsscloud-tests_1  |   Ping XML-RPC to http-post returning XML
mongodb_1         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-27T15:44:00.100+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.4:39892","uuid":"df65fb3a-9913-4075-9671-34d2e9a4d7e8","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":3}}
mongodb_1         | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-27T15:44:00.105+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.4:39892","client":"conn3","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"4.0.1"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.25-linuxkit"},"platform":"Node.js v12.22.3, LE (unified)|Node.js v12.22.3, LE (unified)"}}}
rsscloud-tests_1  |     → MongoDB 'rsscloud' Database Connected
rsscloud-tests_1  |     → Mock server started on port: 8002
rsscloud-tests_1  |     → Mock secure server started on port: 8003
```

Comment: The project is available https://github.com/rsscloud/rsscloud-server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an [intentional change with docker compose](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1613). You can change it back to using `docker-compose` which is different from `docker compose` and will likely provide your expected previous behavior.

Or you can run `docker compose up -d` and `docker compose logs rsscloud-tests` but I'm not sure there's an easy way to do that with `--abort-on-container-exit` since that's likely incompatible with the `-d` option.

I'd recommend following this enhancement request and give it your thumbs up: https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1615

Answer (score 3):

#### As a complement of the given answer:

> I'd recommend following this enhancement request and give it your thumbs up: https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1615

Now we're able to use:

`docker compose up --attach service_name`

This will attach the output to the *service_name*, showing logs just from this service.

PS.: This command only works on *docker compose V2* version which already have a good support for Docker on Windows, but when it comes to linux, the *--attach* argument isn't very well implemented so far. For linux, I would advise to keep using logging driver *(setting it to none if you wish docker not to output logs)*, running docker-compose V1. You may find more information about docker compose V2 at the docs:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/